# PHPmyadmin umlaut is going to be '?'

Tags: php, android, mysql

Im trying to write into my database through android (PHP script).Now... When I want to write a sentence like `"Ich bin Müde"` (German) it saves it like `"Ich bin M?de"`. I already tried to change the collation of my column from `latin1_general_ci` to `latin1_german1_ci` but then I don't get any inputs. So the script is not saving my data into my tables. Is there a easy for a solution? Thanks to everyone

Php script

```
<?php
$hostname = "host";
$username = "admin";
$password = "pass";

$localhost = mysql_connect($hostname,$username,$password)
or
trigger_error(mysql_error(),E_USER_ERROR);

mysql_select_db("db");

$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO tbas VALUES(23,NULL,22,'Ich bin Müde','Ich bin Müde 2'));";
...
?>
```

Comment: it's better to use utf8_general_ci, because your Android app may be passing data in UTF8.

Comment: Doesn't helped. Then theres no input in my table

Comment: please quote the part from PHP where you a) open the database b) insert the line into table

Comment: I edited my first post. Sth like this . But why ?

Comment: after select_db try ` mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
 mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");` and be sure your table is utf8_general_ci, and your PHP page is working under UTF-8.

Comment: Its still not working . Now the words are divided when a umlaut is there for example "Ich bin Müde" is going to be "Ich bin M" . Thanks for your help but do you have any other ideas ?

Comment: What do you mean with "and you PHP page is working under UTF-8" is there any other settings that I can make in phpmyadmin ?

Comment: If that's your PHPMyAdmin inserting umlaut as ?, I think it's because your DB and table column is not in utf8_general_ci.  Please use PHPMyAdmin to fix that.

Comment: And if you want to be sure your PHP page is working under utf8, use header("Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8"); at the beginning of your output.

Comment: I did but now I have no questionmarks anymore but my data is trimmed when a umlaut is there

Comment: Could you please extract the script of the schema of your table?